# What should be my host name in putty configuration for setting up SSH server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a node.js server on AWS EC2 using putty configurations.There I found to configure putty.I stuck filling the hostname of EC2 in putty.What will be the hostname can anyone Help?

screenshot of putty config :
[image: Putty configuration]

Note: I have an EC2 instance launched which I have connect with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After generating the key `.ppk` go to **SSH**-->**Auth**-->**Browse** the .ppk key,
save it and load then open.

Log in with **ec2-user**.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the public ip of your ec2 instance there. which you can find in the aws management console. Attached is the screen-shot for the same.
[image]

Let me know if you are not able to connect with this method.

Comment: yes I have entered public DNS( IPv4) after that it is asking for login: I gave ec2-user but it failed.

Comment: @AdityaJain , which flavor of linux you using ? if its amazon-linux then it takes ec2-user , if ubuntu then uname will be ubuntu.

Comment: I am using amazon-linux.

Comment: I have also generated .ppk with puttygen.

Comment: when I gave ec2-user it displays no supported authentication methods available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a try, we developed an alternative CLI for AWS that makes this much easier: [awless](https://github.com/wallix/awless).

It should work on Windows too and with *awless*, you don't need to set either your IP address nor username, just `awless ssh i-1234` or `awless ssh my-instance-name`.

Note that you may also need to add: `-i path/to/your/key.pem` if the key was not created with awless.